# PHP laravel Flash message is not showing

Tags: php, laravel

I am redirected to the desired page but success message is supposed to be shown there but there is no message has been shown.
I have tried multiple methods online but there is something I missing.

Controller File:

```php
public function store(Request $request) {
    $inputs = $request->all();

    // logger("I am here");
    $request->validate([
      'first_name' => 'required',
      'last_name' => 'required',
      'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
      'phone_number' => 'required',
      'dob' => 'required|date'
    ]);

    // dd($inputs);

    $user = User::create([
      'first_name' => $inputs['first_name'],
      'last_name' => $inputs['last_name'],
      'email' => $inputs['email'],
      'phone_number' => $inputs['phone_number'],
      'dob' => $inputs['dob'],
      'role_id'=> 2
    ]);

    $user->session()->flash('success', 'your account has been created.'); 

    return redirect('/');
    // dd('success validation');
}
```

Blade File:

```
@if (session()->has('success'))
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    <p>{{ session('success') }}</p>
  </div>
@endif
```

Comment: try `Session::flash('success', 'your account has been created.'); `

Comment: throws an error

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: Likely a namespacing issue with the suggestion above. Add `use Session;` to the top of your file, or try some alternatives:  `\Session::flash(...)`, or `session()->flash(...)`, or maybe even `$request->session()->flash(...)`. `$user->session()->flash(...)` doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Session::flash('success', 'your account has been created!');
```

or there is another method called with() you can use it after redirect()

```
return redirect()
            ->with('success', 'your account has been created');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$user` is a model, and can not use `->session()`.

You can redirect with flashed session data :

```
return redirect('/')->with('success', 'your account has been created.');
```

Blade :

```
@if (session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: This doesn't worked for me

Comment: It's really funny. This is the [basic of HTTP redirect](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data). If that doesn't work, there's something wrong with your code.